# How can I keep vertex order the same on every Instantiate()?

Tags: unity, geometry, instancing

While trying to resolve [another question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/88144), I have discovered that if I [Instantiate()](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) from a prefab, the order of the mesh vertices (and therefore triangles) is inconsistent between instances. This is apparent, for example, if I [RaycastHit.triangleIndex](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-triangleIndex.html) the same location on the mesh on different runs of the game. The same location returns the same triangle index during one run of the game, but a different triangle index in the next run.

If instead I add the model to the scene in the editor, and then run the game, the same location returns the same triangle index in every run of the game. If I duplicate the model through the scene editor, the duplicate also returns the same triangle index. This is the behaviour I am aiming for.

However, I would obviously prefer to Instantiate at runtime. (This would allow me flexibility on when and how many models to instantiate, and in the long run I want to add other models too. The alternative is to add the model to the scene and create a large number of "offscreen" duplicates, which seems prone to inefficiencies on multiple fronts.)

Is it possible to use Instantiate **and** maintain a consistent vertex/triangle order between instances and between runs of the game?